# SSIS 2008 R2 Excel Connection Manager Issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel-2010, etl, ssis-2008

I have a excel connection manager as destination.
My local machine is 32 bit and package runs fine locally.
When deployed to server which is a 64-bit machine, package fails with below error.

can some one help ?

I tried all online available options:

`run64bitruntime` to true/false

`delay validation` to True

etc.....

> Error: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0xC00F9304
>      Source: RiverStone_Extract Connection manager "RiverStone_Extract"
>      Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED: The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS, as no OLE DB provider is available.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0xC020801C
>      Source: RiverStone Extract & Tgt Control Totals Excel Destination [1017]
>      Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "RiverStone_Extract" failed with error code 0xC00F9304.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0xC0047017
>      Source: RiverStone Extract & Tgt Control Totals SSIS.Pipeline
>      Description: component "Excel Destination" (1017) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>   End Error
>
> Progress: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Source: RiverStone Extract & Tgt Control Totals 
>      Validating: 100% complete
>   End Progress
>   Error: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0xC004700C
>      Source: RiverStone Extract & Tgt Control Totals SSIS.Pipeline
>      Description: One or more component failed validation.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0xC0024107
>      Source: RiverStone Extract & Tgt Control Totals 
>      Description: There were errors during task validation.
>   End Error
>
> Warning: 2017-06-13 20:33:46.53
>      Code: 0x80019002
>      Source: RiverStone_Extract 
>      Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (5) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Given this part of the error message

```
The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS
```

It would appear that you are trying to run the package using the 64bit 'execution mode'

Assuming you have a 32bit MS Office installation change your project so that it [runs as 32bit](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/faq%20-%20how%20to%20run%20ssis%20packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm).

You may need to take this into consideration if scheduling via [SQL Server's Job Agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/06/12/use-32bit-runtime-option-for-sql-agent/)

Comment: Tried setting run64bit to false, didn't work. I am scheduling job through autosys to run ... any other thoughts ?

Comment: I am not familiar with autosys, if it is essentially a command line than try  [DTExec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) from "Programs (x86)"

Comment: Autosys is a scheduling tool , just like SQL agent .... the set up we have at client side (which i cannot change) is setting package connections from a table, so command line is out of box situation.

Comment: Can you install the [64bit ACE driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on the server? Is the 32bit driver installed on the server? n.b. You cannot install both the 32bit and 64bit ACE drivers on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggested Solutions

**1. Install Microsoft Access 2010 Data Engine 64-Bit**

You can Install Microsoft Access 2010 Data Engine 64-Bit from the following link:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

**2. Make the SQL Agent Job run in 32-bit**

Follow one of the following links to learn more:

- [Running 32-bit SSIS in a 64-bit Environment](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx)
- [SSIS Package Not Running as 32bit in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311938/ssis-package-not-running-as-32bit-in-sql-server-2012)

**3. Other Helpful Links**

- [schedule the 64-bit SQL Server Agent to run a package by using the 32-bit version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/934653/how-to-use-the-64-bit-sql-server-agent-to-schedule-a-sql-server-2005-integration-services-package)
- [Quick Reference: SSIS in 32- and 64-bits](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html)