# ssis script component error connecting to Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis, etl, script-component

I have c# code connecting to and pulling data from a SharePoint list working fine when called from a console application configured to run as 64bit.  When I invoke the same code configured for 64bit, I get the following error within an SSIS script component.  Any thoughts?

> Script component has encountered an exception in user code:
>
> Project Name: SC_a3876f743db745348104a282555fada0
>
> **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {BDEADF26-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**
>
> at MyCRMNamespace.MyCRM.LoadList(String siteUrl, String listName)
> at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()    at
> UserComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 Outputs, Int32[] OutputIDs,
> PipelineBuffer[] Buffers, OutputNameMap OutputMap)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32
> outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing the package from Visual Studio, try changing the `Run64bitRuntime` property value and re-run the package. You can refer to the following link:

- [Run an SSIS Package in 32 Bit Mode](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Run-an-SSIS-Package-in-32-Bit-Mode?language=en_US)

If you are executing the SSIS package from an SQL agent job or SSIS catalog, you can change this property from the management studio as mentioned in the following link *check the question and answer)*:

- [SSIS Package Not Running as 32bit in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311938/ssis-package-not-running-as-32bit-in-sql-server-2012)